# I am getting 2 Error messages in Unity and cannot figure out how to fix it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im getting 2 error messages and can't figure out how to fix them.

```
Assets\Scripts\you.cs(14,62): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'you.speed'

Assets\Scripts\you.cs(25,58): error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'position' and no accessible extension method 'position' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Maybe some could help me?
the character should only be able to jump once before hitting the ground otherwise it can just fly away.
i have a groundcheck object in the engine attached to the character but i keep getting these errors.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class you : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float upForce = 100f;
    public LayerMask ground;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float speed = 20f;
    public bool isgrounded = true;
    public float checkradius = 0.5f;
    public GameObject groundcheck;
    public float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;

    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(translation, 0, 0);
        isgrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundcheck.position, checkradius, ground);


        if (isDead == false)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
            {
                rb2d.velocity = Vector2.zero;
                rb2d.AddForce(new Vector2(0, upForce));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the translation when you instantiate the object, using user input? It seems to me that you would want to do that in the `Update` method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
```

Cannot be field because **speed** is not static field. Change it to a static/const and it should be working fine.

```
        isgrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundcheck.position, checkradius, ground);
```

The groundcheck is a gameobject, gameobject has "transform" which has position, so please change it to **groundcheck.transform.position**.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the now static `speed` field is shared by every instance of the `you` class. If `you` is in fact a singleton, you won't run into any issues, but if this class were to be used to represent multiple objects you would need to understand that now if you change `speed` on one "instance" you are changing it for all instances, which may not be what was intended.

Answer (score -2):

For the first message the field initialization should work with constant values.

```csharp
public class you : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const float InitialSpeed = 20f; 
    public float upForce = 100f;
    public LayerMask ground;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float speed = InitialSpeed; // Here 
    public bool isgrounded = true;
    public float checkradius = 0.5f;
    public GameObject groundcheck;
    public float translation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * InitialSpeed; // And Here

// Rest of the code
```

About the second error the "position" property comes from transform. [Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-position.html) Maybe you mean:

```
isgrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundcheck.transform.position, checkradius, ground);
```

Comment: It should be `groundcheck.transform.position`